# Nginx Location Block Alias

Tags: nginx, location, block, alias

I'm having trouble getting my head around why a location alias I'm trying to configure isn't working.

```
location /i/ {
   alias /var/www/vhosts/example.com/html/wp-content/images/;
}
```

If I browse to **https://example.com/i/logo.jpg**, I get a 404, and in the logs I see:
"/var/www/vhosts/example.com/html/i/logo.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory)

If I hit **https://example.com/i/**, I get a 403 forbidden, as it tries to list the contents of the alias's real directory (correct behaviour).

If I hit **https://example.com/i** (note the lack of trailing /) then the request spins forever and times out (correct behaviour).

So I tried regex instead, and came up with this:

```
location ~ ^/i/(\.*)$ {
   alias /var/www/vhosts/example.com/html/wp-content/images/;
}
```

However this displays the same behaviour as the firs location block mentioned above.

So I tried to use root directive instead, but this is not desirable, as root uses the $uri string in the request, so would end up appending /i/ to the end of the /images/ path.

*So my question is, how can I server all static content (images et al) from /var/www/vhosts/example.com/html/wp-content/images/ publicly under the URL alias of https://example.com/i/filenamehere.jpg? Am I missing something obvious? Or does Nginx just not really like doing this?*

For clarity, running Nginx 1.12.0, PHP7-FPM

Comment: You must have another location that is processing `.jpg` files - or you have not restarted `nginx`. Try: `nginx -t` to test your configuration.

Comment: Hi, I do have a location block that catches .jpg files, but I figured as the one mentioned above was before it in the config it would take precedence?

The location block catching jpg files is:
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
       expires 1M;
    }

Comment: Only regular expression `location` blocks are ordered. You can make `/i/` take precedence by using the `^~` modifier. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Comment: Perfect, thats now working following your advice. Thanks so much. Appreciated.